# launching ise14.6 on ubuntu 12.4

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, launch, xilinx-ise

I have installed "ise14.6" on "ubuntu".but after installation, I do not know how to launch it.
I have read somewhere that I must source setting.sh .but there is no such file in folder i have installed "ise14.6" .would you please help. I need for launching it and after that i must launch license configuration manager to load a new license.
thanks
regards

Answer (score 1):

Config scripts path: $BASE/Xilinx/14.6/ISE_DS/

For 32-bit:

- ISE: $BASE/Xilinx/14.6/ISE_DS/ISE/bin/lin64/ise
- License Manager: BASE/Xilinx/14.6/ISE_DS/common/bin/lin/xlmc

For 64-bit:

- ISE: $BASE/Xilinx/14.6/ISE_DS/ISE/bin/lin64/ise
- License Manager: $BASE/Xilinx/14.6/ISE_DS/common/bin/lin64/xlmc

Note, the standard $BASE install directory is /opt